# Color drop pixel on webpage and get its css rule

Tags: css

I would like to pick a pixel on a webpage and get the css rule dictating that pixels color and which rules that rule overrides, is that possible?

Comment: Not every pixel's colour is dictated by a single rule, things like opacity/blend modes/text-anti-aliasing all create colours that aren't explicitly set in any one single rule.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I can see why someone might. You've explained the goal, but not given any context, e.g.  Are you looking for external software? Browser dev-tool options? A way to write some code that does this? etc.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly picking a pixel, but what you can do is open the developer console, which on Google Chrome on macOS is Option + Command + J, or on Windows/Linux is Shift + Ctrl + J. In the top left corner of the developer console is a Select Element button, and when clicking that, you can select an element on the page, which in your case is the element in which the pixel is located. In the middle tab is a Styles tab, which shows all the CSS code for the classes, ids, element, and in-line CSS for that particular element. This shows the color of the element, and all the overridden CSS rules, which are crossed off. This is a picture of the developer console:

[image]

Comment: Yes, and then I have to go through parents.